# how to Replace urls by 4 count in editext if detected

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext

i want to have edittext of 300 char limit but i have a requirement that if detected urls in edittext then it should replace the count by 4 keeping the urls as such

for example :--

1. If i paste

   `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` -->should display textview count limit 296/300 and also editext to upto 296 char limit for entering

2. If i paste

   `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask hi`-->should display textview count limit 293/300 and also editext to upto 293 char limit for entering

Comment: do mean make  the size of url  is 4 when count the 300 char limit?

Comment: while pasting url it should consider the url length as 4 @Matrix

Answer (score 0):

### Sample

---

[This is the sample video](https://streamable.com/w35rn7)

---

Why don't you try this class ? This will calculate the length of the text with a url equal to 4 chars.

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Patterns;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class CustomEditText extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText {

    private int charCount = 0;

    public CustomEdiText(Context context, AttributeSet set) {
        super(context, set);
    }

    public CustomEdiText(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
        List<String> urls = extractUrls(text.toString());

        String removedText = text.toString();
        if(urls.size() != 0){
            for (String mText: urls) {
                removedText = text.toString().replaceAll(mText,"    ");
            }
            charCount = removedText.length();
            return;
        }

        charCount = text.toString().length();
    }

    public int getCharCount(){
        return charCount;
    }

    private List<String> extractUrls(String input) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] words = input.split("\\s+");

        Pattern pattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;
        for(String word : words)
            if (pattern.matcher(word).find())
                result.add(word);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(text, type);
        List<String> urls = extractUrls(text.toString());

        String removedText = text.toString();
        if(urls.size() != 0){
            for (String mText: urls) {
                removedText = text.toString().replaceAll(mText,"    ");
            }
            charCount = removedText.length();
            return;
        }

        charCount = text.toString().length();
    }
}
```

You can use it just as a normal edit text class.

**To get the length, you can call :**

```java
editText.getCharCount();
```

Don't use `.length()` or you will get wrong result

This can be a example code:

```java
binding.urlEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "afterTextChanged: " + binding.urlEditText.getCharCount());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does this answer help u?